# Undo specific specific changes while keeping older changes in a mysql DB

Tags: mysql, transactions

I want to rollback some changes while preserving other changes which have been done after.

```
Change 1 ( update statement on table A )
Change 2 ( insert statement on table B using table A)
```

I want to rollback change 1 but not 2 but can accept work around my requirement :

1. Is there a way to target change 1 and only rollback this one ?
2. Is there a way to rollback the changes while preserving a table (B) ?
3. Is there a way to rollback everything except insert's ?
4. Is there a way to rollback the table A but not the other tables ?
5. Is there a way to rollback only one type of change (update) ?

As transactions are meant to be atomic, I guess the strict answer is no but I'm asking of a work around here.

I have something of an answer at the moment which consists to save the data in temporary tables but it is heavy and not evolutionary : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64d1f/1

My question is related to the following : [Nested transaction rollback between two savepoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727697/nested-transaction-rollback-between-two-savepoints)
but mine is less restrictive ( You can answer my question without answering this one but answering this one would definitely answer mine ).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to create a custom audit log file to give you very granular control of what you roll back.
Given there are only 3 things (add,change,delete)which can happen to rows in table than you could design an audit log like this:
Id        -auto increment,
timestamp -date and time of add,change,delete,
action    - A,C,D,
Table_id  -the table being actioned,
Before_image - make this as big as you think you will need for all the fields in the tables you wish to log,
After_image

Logically 
if you 
INSERT then you insert to the table being actioned and the audit log After_image
UPDATE you insert the before_image from the table being actioned and the after_image with the change.
DELETE you insert the before_image from the table being actioned before you physically delete it

If you want to roll back any or all of these elements you have enough info in the audit log to do so. Clearly the roll back code is the reverse of the inserts to the audit log (an insert becomes a delete , and update takes the after_image and updates the table being actioned and a delete becomes an insert from the before_img to the table being actioned).

Comment: So you advice to create a log file that would record every change and retain enough information so that I can apply the opposite change.
So rather than teleporting to a previous state, it would make the same distance in the opposite direction. 
I think I can do this, it would be powerful and pretty light (in CPU usage).
I will validate when I will have achieve it.