# commit a specific transaction nested within another transaction - coldfusion - hibernate

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, cfml

there is a code snippet that needs to be executed even if the parent transaction enters catch and rollack

```java
transaction action="begin" nested="true" isolation="read_uncommitted"{
  try{
    transaction {
      //more code...
    }
    transaction{
      //my code that needs to be committed anyway, even though the parent transaction of rollback
    }

  }catch(Any e){
     transaction action="rollback";
  }
}
```

this is a very simplified example of my current code. How do I force commit this single point of code?

Comment: Is it the second transaction dependent on the first one?  If not, why are they nested?  If so, what happens if the first one gets rolled back?

Comment: the second transaction is deeply nested, and this second transaction depends on parameters obtained within certain functions. Basically this transaction that I need to work would be a log for the bank.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `finally{}` code block.  See documentation [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/extending-coldfusion-pages-with-cfml-scripting/handling-exceptions.html).

```
transaction action="begin" nested="true" isolation="read_uncommitted"{
  try{
    transaction {
      //more code...
    }
  }catch(Any e){
     transaction action="rollback";
  }finally {
    transaction{
      //my code that needs to be committed anyway, even though the parent transaction of rollback
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't move the code to finally, there are too many trading rules inside the transaction and there are too many transaction threads. No possibility to create a new flow for a specific transaction?

Comment: What's an example of a "new flow" and how would it be different than using finally?

Comment: You can either move your code out of the transaction (which you want to be executed anyway) after the transaction. That way you are ensuring that it runs right after the transaction regardless of its status.

**OR**

you could run that code after the rollback in the catch as you said you can't move it in the finally block. 

Hope it helps.

Comment: @SOS the second transaction is deeply nested, and this second transaction depends on parameters obtained within certain functions. I thought there was a way to make a partial commit of a single transaction without affecting or being affected by another transaction, but apparently it's not possible.

Comment: @akashb I'm actually going to have to do some code refactoring to suit my needs. As I explained in one of the comments, the code is deeply nested, I wouldn't want to have to do the refactoring, but if it's the only option I'll have to.

Comment: @JonathanCominRibeiro - Yes, I saw the comment about it being deeply nested, but without a clearer picture of the flow, wasn't sure why that meant it couldn't be executed elsewhere (separately, inside the "catch" clause, inside "finally", etc...). Some databases support savepoints, which theoretically allow you to rollback a portion of the work done so far. However, they have limitations.  You can't pick and chose what gets committed or rolled back arbitrarily or out of order, so I think the answer to your question is "not possible"  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14740473/8895292